# Raspberry Pi 4 power / heat issues

Tags: usb, boot-issues, retropie, pi-4

I recently bought a Pi 4 to replace an older Pi 3, but I am experiencing a couple of issues which could make it nearly useless.

- I am using a Pandora Box 5 as a game controller. It's a game console with 2 arcade joysticks and a USB connector, it worked like a charm with the Pi 3, but now, as soon as I connect the USB, every other device is disabled. Maybe it's a power issue?
- The temperature is quite high, the warning icon is flashing already when NOOB starts, before even installing anything.
- A Retropie microSD which worked flawlessly with the Pi 3 is not booting anymore, I tried flashing it again, but it just does not work. Only the NOOB vfat-formatted card is working.

Am I doing something wrong? Probably. Has anybody experienced the same issues? Any idea for a solution? Thanks.

Comment: What power supply are you using?

Comment: The official Retropie is not yet Pi4 compatible.

Comment: I'm using the official raspberry pi USB-C power supply.

Comment: @CoderMike: I've read that I can install Lakka using NOOBS, but I can't find it on the list of OS I can install (connected using Ethernet, the other OS are available)

Answer (score 3):

I can't help with Pandora or Retropie, but I do believe I have a workable solution for your heat issues.

I too have an RPi 4 and I immediately noticed that it ran warm.  Actually, it idled warm and ran hot.  I waited for firmware updates to appear and I installed heat sinks.  The heat sinks lowered the idle temp, but had little effect on run temps.  The early reports on the firmware changes sounded about the same.  To measure you temps, take a look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=34994

I ordered a fan shim from Pimoroni.  The URL is https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/fan-shim.  Shipping it from merry old England to Phoenix USA took quite a while, but when I installed the fan, run temperatures dropped a lot.  I haven't used my new Pi all that much because I was concerned about the long term effects of running it hot, so my observations won't mean much.  OTOH, there are detailed reports available that convinced me to purchase the fan shim. One is at: https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/pimoroni-fan-shim-heatsink-raspberry-pi-4,6219.html.

The fan is very simple to install, assuming that you have the visual acuity and manual dexterity to handle some very, very small bolts - seriously small.  There is software to manage the fan which is readily available and easy to install.  I used the instructions for installing both the hardware and software at: https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/getting-started-with-fan-shim.

I'd buy this again.  If it is available now from a US distributor, I'd do that rather than pine away for days waiting for it to arrive.  BTW, I'm a spoiled Amazon Prime customer.

Comment: I'll try that, but I guess it would not fit into the official case anymore (or if it did, the fan would be useless). And of course, it would draw more power. I only hope it's not too loud.

Comment: I can't tell you if it will fit in the official case.  An enclosed, or largely enclosed, case certainly won't help circulation.  I run a GeauxRobot case which has open sides.  Even with the open sides, I can not hear the fan on a Pi sitting 2 feet away.  My experience says not to worry about the noise.